# SQL Server 2008 index fragmentation problem

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, indexing

Everyday I import 2,000,000 rows from some text files using `BULK INSERT` into SQL Server 2008 and then I do some post-processing to update the records.

I have some indexes on the table to execute the post-process as fast as possible and in normal situation, the post-processing script takes about 40 seconds to run.

But sometimes (I don't know when) the post-processing does not work. In the situation I've mentioned, it is not done after an hour! After rebuilding indexes, everything is fine and normal.

What should I do to prevent the problem to be happened?

Right now, I have a nightly job to rebuild all indexes. Why the index fragmentation grows up to 90%?

Update: 
Here is my table which I import text file into:

```
  CREATE TABLE [dbo].[My_Transactions](
    [My_TransactionId] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [FileId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [RowNo] [int] NOT NULL,
    [TransactionTypeId] [smallint] NOT NULL,
    [TransactionDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [TransactionNumber] [dbo].[TransactionNumber] NOT NULL,
    [CardNumber] [dbo].[CardNumber] NULL,
    [AccountNumber] [dbo].[CardNumber] NULL,
    [BankCardTypeId] [smallint] NOT NULL,
    [AcqBankId] [smallint] NOT NULL,
    [DeviceNumber] [dbo].[DeviceNumber] NOT NULL,
    [Amount] [dbo].[Amount] NOT NULL,
    [DeviceTypeId] [smallint] NOT NULL,
    [TransactionFee] [dbo].[Amount] NOT NULL,
    [AcqSwitchId] [tinyint] NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [_dta_index_Jam_Transactions_8_1290487676__K1_K4_K12_K6_K11_5] ON [dbo].[Jam_Transactions] 
(
    [Jam_TransactionId] ASC,
    [TransactionTypeId] ASC,
    [Amount] ASC,
    [TransactionNumber] ASC,
    [DeviceNumber] ASC
)
INCLUDE ( [TransactionDate]) WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [_dta_index_Jam_Transactions_8_1290487676__K12_K6_K11_K1_5] ON [dbo].[Jam_Transactions] 
(
    [Amount] ASC,
    [TransactionNumber] ASC,
    [DeviceNumber] ASC,
    [Jam_TransactionId] ASC
)
INCLUDE ( [TransactionDate]) WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_Jam_Transactions] ON [dbo].[Jam_Transactions] 
(
    [Jam_TransactionId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried just refreshing the statistics after such a large insert:

```
UPDATE STATISTICS my_table
```

My experience with large bulk inserts is that the statistics get all mangled up and need a refreshed afterwards, it's also much faster than running a REINDEX or index REORDER.

Another option is to look into padding the index, you likely have no padding fill factor on your indexes meaning that if your index is:

```
A, B, D, E, F
```

and you insert a value with a `CardNumber` of C, then your index will look like:

```
A, B, D, E, F, C
```

and hence be ~20% fragmented, if you instead specify a fill factor for your index of say 15% we would see it look like roughly:

```
A, B, D, _, E, F
```

(Note the internal the empty space is put roughly in the middle point of the fillfactor % not at the end)

So that when you insert the C value it is closer to being correct, but it actually sees that the D is just swapped with the C and usually moves the D at that point.

Beyond that, are you sure that the fragmentation is actually the problem, as part of reindexing the table is read and loaded entirely into memory (provided it fits) and thus any query you run on it will be very fast.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of including this table in the nightly job, why don't you make index maintenance (on this table specifically) part of the nightly import job, between `BULK INSERT` and whatever 'post-processing' is?

We don't have enough information to know *why* the index fragmentation grows that quickly. Which index(es)? How many indexes are there? What is the order of the data in the file?

You may also consider using the `ORDER` option in the `BULK INSERT` statement to change the way the data is inserted. It may make the load take longer but it should reduce the need to reorganize. Again depending on the order of the source data and the index(es) that become fragmented.

Finally, what is the impact of rebuilding/not rebuilding or reorganizing/not reorganizing the indexes? Have you tried both? Perhaps it makes the post-processing run quicker if you rebuild, but perhaps only a defragment is necessary. And while it may make the post-processing quicker, what about the queries that are run against the table later in the day? Have you done any metrics against those to see if they speed up or slow down depending on what you do at night?

Comment: Thanks, the main problem is that I have 100,000,000 records exisiting on the table and rebuilding the indexes takes a long time, so it doesn't seem rebuilding all indexes (after inserting 500,000 new records) could be the best solution.
I have 4 indexes (one clustered index on PK Identity, and 3 non-clustered ascending indexes on TransactionTime, CardNumber, and TransactionNumber). All of my fields are bigint.

Comment: You should look at partitioning this table, if possible, you might be able to rebuild just a portion of the table then.

Comment: @SqlACID beat me to it... certainly sounds like a case for partitioning.

Answer (score 0):

Does your main table keep growing by 2 million rows per day or is there a lot of deleting taking place as well?  Could you bulk insert into a temporary import table and do your processing prior to inserting into the main table?  You can always use hints to force your queries to use certain indices:

```
SELECT *
FROM your_table_name WITH (INDEX(your_index_name))
WHERE your_column_name = 5
```

Comment: I do not delete any record. My steps are: 1- Insert into the RAW data table from a text file. 2- User approves. 3- Process approved records. 4- Insert processed records in another table (without any change on RAW data table).
  Sometimes high value of index fragmentation, causes the process section to be failed.

Comment: By "failed" you mean "slow" right? There is a big distinction. Suddenly it's unclear to me how fragmentation causes the insert to be slow. Fragmentation where? On the raw table, or on the destination table? Are you checking this fragmentation before or after you observe the slowness issue? When this happens, is there anything different about the data that's being inserted? For more specific help you're really going to need to provide much more detail about the questions I asked in my question (the index(es) where you observe fragmentation, the nature of the data in the file).

Comment: By "failed" I mean after 2 hours it wasn't completed, then I stopped it! In normal condition, it took 30 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

I would try taking the index offline before a mass row insertion and  the bring it back online after the mass row insertion.  Much, much more faster as compared to re-indexing, or performing a drop and create index..... difference is that the index is there data is being stored but the index is currently not being used, "Offline" until it is brought back "Online".  I have a 1.5 million row insertion process and had a problem with one of my non clustered indexes fragmenting which was causing poor performance.  Went form 99% fragmentation to .14% using the MSSQL Offline Online Index option....

Code sample:

```
ALTER INDEX idx_a ON dbo.tbl_A
REBUILD WITH (ONLINE = OFF);
```

Toggle between OFF and ON and you are good to go....

Comment: This actually does NOT take the index offline.  It rebuilds the index with the Table offline, i.e. NO OTHER PROCESS CAN USE IT.  Of course this ends up with almost no fragmentation because what this does in the background is DROPS the index and CREATEs it from scratch.